# Error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : junit/framework/TestCase when running TestDFSIO in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

when i try to run TestDFSIO in Hadoop ubuntu i got "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : junit/framework/TestCase" i dont know to to fix it.

this is my command to run testdfsio
"yarn jar /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-3.3.5-tests.jar -write -nrFiles 10 -Filesize 1000"

Answer (score 0):

I believe any `-tests` JAR file is for the Hadoop source code unit tests, and are ran during the build of the project, and not intended to be ran against a real YARN cluster.

More specifically, YARN classpath does not include test libraries, such as JUnit